# Remove MongoDB document using MDBC module in PowerShell

Tags: mongodb, powershell, document

In my project, I use the MDBC module to connect to a MongoDB, recover the data and connecting me to a SQL database.

I'm looking at whether MongoDB data exists in the SQL database, and if not, I remove those that do not exist.

I already do everything except delete.

```
Import-Module Mdbc;

function New-MissionMongo {
    Param(
        # Your Server's URL
        [string]
        $Url = "mongodb://localhost:27017",
        # Database to connect to
        [string]
        $Db = "ref-planning",
        # Collection Name
        [string] 
        $CollectionName = "planning",
        # Where do we want to put that information
        [string] 
        $Path = "C:\Users\user\Documents\MISSIONS\test\$collectionName.json",
        # Default Limit
        [int16] 
        $Limit = 1
    )
    Connect-Mdbc $Url $Db $CollectionName;
    $d = New-MdbcData;
    $d.tenant = "spo"
    $d.isTemplate = $false
    $data = Get-MdbcData $d -Property reference, tenant, entities -As PS
    Write-Host $data.entities[0]
    $split1 = $data.entities[0].split(":") 
    $countEntities = $data.entities.count

     foreach ($planning in $data) {
        $numPlanning =  $planning.entities.split(":")[4]

        # This is an exemple of how my data looks like, not the real data.
        #
        # $planning.entities content:
        #
        # entities          
        # --------   
        # {urn:CodeDomaine:LOOOZDEE:CodeDossier:0478718652}
        # {urn:CodeDomaine:LOOOZDEE:CodeDossier:08747478798-2}
        # {urn:CodeDomaine:LOOOZDEE:CodeDossier:017874776}
        # {urn:CodeDomaine:LOOOZDEE:CodeDossier:01849849245}
        #
        # $numPlanning content:
        #
        # 0478718652
        # 08747478798-2
        # 017874776
        # 01849849245

        $temp00 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT iddoss FROM DOMOPE WHERE iddoss = '$numPlanning';" -Username "sage" -Password "sage" -ServerInstance "localhost" -Database "SPO_Next" -OutputSqlErrors $true -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($temp00 -eq $null) {
            ### Here is where I need help, I 'm trying to delete a
            ### document, using an object ($planning)

            # $planning content:
            #
            # _id                      entities                                           tenant reference
            # ---                      --------                                           ------ ---------
            # 5d63d96a7ddd344700721  {urn:CodeDomaine:LOOOZDEE:CodeDossier:0478718652}    aaa    BazZ7k4WrxE
            # 5d63d96a7ddd37400714   {urn:CodeDomaine:LOOOZDEE:CodeDossier:08747478798-2} aaa    8qhK5DwoZ
            # 5d63d478dd34385ee0072a {urn:CodeDomaine:LOOOZDEE:CodeDossier:017874776}     aaa    Haz7AZ5v1E
            # 5d63d7DE756014e00726   {urn:CodeDomaine:LOOOZDEE:CodeDossier:01849849245}   aaa    Hgf48a7zAyN

            Remove-MdbcData -Query $planning.entities -Collection $CollectionName
            $planning
        }
    }
}

New-MissionMongo
```

How do I delete the MongoDB documents that contains this data?

Comment: `$planning.entities` looks like a list of objects. Is that the case? And you want to remove those entities that match the values listed in `$numPlanning`? Then something like this might work: `$planning.entities | ? {$_.CodeDossier -in $numPlanning} | % { Remove-MdbcData -Query $_ -Collection $collectionName`.

Comment: So, did you try my suggestion? Does it work?

Comment: I try your suggestion but it's not work because `$planning.entities` is an object which contain a list of string. `urn:CodeDomaine:LOOOZDEE:CodeDossier:0478718652` is a string for example.
And when you do :  `$planning.entities | ? {$_.CodeDossier -in $numPlanning}`, you cant have the `CodeDossier` after the pipe because the result of `$planning.entities` is a string

That is why I split the `$data` (remenber `$data` is the `$planning` in the `foreach`). To have the `CodeDossier`, I split it like that : `$split1 = $data.entities[0].split(":")`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the output of `$planning.entities | Get-Member`.